# Why were the SRB cameras looking down called "forward cameras"?

Tags: space-shuttle, camera

The Space Shuttle SRBs had cameras as well, one of them on each SRB was looking down just like the ET camera that streamed live during launches. Those down-looking SRB cameras were referred to as the left and right forward camera. Why is this? Isn't looking in the direction it flies from "backward" rather than "forward"?

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCKHXbAKOWs) footage from the "forward" cameras.

Comment: Perhaps "forward" isn't referring to the direction the camera is looking, but rather where on the SRB the camera is located, just as locations are indicated on a ship or vessel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because the camera is on the forward end of the SRB. See the names of the two skirts, for instance.

[image: SRB schematic]